# Explanation of an integral formula for the expectation of $(X_1-X_2)(Y_1-Y_2)$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I do not  understand the proof of this expression. Who can explain it to me using simpler words?

[image]

[image]

***I do not understand the following black part:***

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular part that you don't understand?

Comment: The PROOF process

Comment: [Source](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=XV8KAAAAMAAJ&q=%22lemma+2+hoeffding%22&dq=%22lemma+2+hoeffding%22)?

Comment: Well that narrows it down...

Comment: I do not understand the black part.

Comment: But why the black part equals the final result? Thanks again!

Comment: @eric $X_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $X_1<X_2$. If $u<X_1$ and $u<X_2$ then $I(u,X_1)-I(u,X_2)=0$. If $u>X_1$ and $u<X_2$ then $I(u,X_2)-I(u,X_1)=1$. If $u>X_2$ and $u>X_1$ then $I(u,X_1)-I(u,X_2)=0$ again. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty[I(u,X_1)-I(u,X_2)]du&=\int_{-\infty}^{X_1} 0du + \int_{X_1}^{X_2} 1 du +\int_{X_2}^\infty 0 du \\
&= \int^{X_2}_{X_1} 1 du \\
&= (X_2-X_1)\\
\end{align}
$$
If $X_2<X_1$ then 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty[I(u,X_1)-I(u,X_2)]du&=\int_{-\infty}^{X_2} 0du + \int_{X_2}^{X_1} -1 du +\int_{X_1}^\infty 0 du \\
&= \int^{X_1}_{X_2} -1 du \\
&= (X_2-X_1)\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks very much!!! Do you know the following expressions?

Comment: But why the black part equals the final result?

Comment: @eric $E(X_2-X_1)=E($this integral$)$.

Comment: Yes, I mean why E(this integral)= the right part of (3.1). Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @eric I think you need to give it a little more effort, you are asking another question about this after only a few minutes.

Comment: Dear suzy Hirose, I revised the question again. Please check the original question and find "The second questions is why the following expression is right? ". Thanks very much!

Comment: @eric **S**uz**u** not suzy. First, answer this. $E(I(u,X_1))=?$ Then unwrap the terms in brackets keeping in mind that $X_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent. It is not very difficult.

Comment: Sorry,I still can not understand....Could explain it more detail?

Comment: Hi Suzu, are you online?